# What is WebApplication in SharePoint?

Tags: web-application

What is Web Application in SharePoint please describe briefly

Comment: First result from google. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31034.what-is-a-web-application-in-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A SharePoint 2013 web application is composed of an Internet Information Services (IIS) web site that acts as a logical unit for the site collections that you create. Before you can create a site collection, you must first create a Web application. Each web application is represented by a different IIS web site with a unique or shared application pool. [read more here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261875.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

In SharePoint, when we create web application it has multiple componenets.

- IIS site on the server
- Port number, URL
- Content Database
- Authentication provider
- Application Pool

Once you have your web application created then you can have multiple site collections in it. Check the hierarchy:[image]

http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/sharepoint-terminology-farm-web-application-site-collection-top-level-site/

Answer (score 0):

A Web Application is an extended IIS Web Site. When you create a Web Application in SharePoint a new IIS Web Site is created. SharePoint then modifies the global.asax file, modifies the web.config file, and creates some virtual directories that point to the SharePoint System folders.